# What's the cheapest temporary shower wall option?

Tags: walls, shower, saving-money

I'm looking for a temporary solution that doesn't cost a lot of any money. I have basic construction skills (about the average home owner), so anything too complicated to install isn't a good option.

The shower has a tub. The required walls measure 60*30*67 (L*w*H) (67 inches from tub to ceiling, not floor to ceiling). The tub is 15 inches tall.

Again, I'm looking for the cheapest solution that's waterproof, I don't care how it looks.

Comment: Buy a roll of vapor barrier and tape it to the wall with duct tape. You DID say cheapest right...

Comment: If your looking for something real, then the plastic liners are probably your best bet.. Something like this http://www.homedepot.com/p/Allura-31-in-x-60-1-2-in-x-58-in-5-Piece-Easy-Up-Adhesive-Tub-Wall-in-White-40184/204338499

Answer (score 1):

Staple a vinyl shower curtain to each wall, lapping the sides fully. Let it extend adequately into the tub at the bottom.

If you use poly sheeting from a hardware store I recommend 4 mil. You'll want to roll the top edge several times before stapling.